# For loop tricks

Tags: c++, for-loop

I made this code to prompt the user for a number that is not 5, otherwise the game ends. If the user enters a number 10 times it should show the winning message. However, I find myself struggling in not showing the winning message if the user enters 5. What could I do to only print the failure message when the user enters 5 and not both? Also, is there a way of making my code simpler?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << "- enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    if (number == 5)
    { cout << "you were not supposed to enter 5!\n"; // Failure message
      break;
    }
}

cout << "Wow, you're more patient than I am, you win.\n"; // winner message
```

Comment: `bool did_user_enter_5 = false;` ... `if(number == 5) {did_user_enter_5 = true; ...}` ... `if(!did_user_enter_5) cout << "Wow, ...` is one way that works. You could also use `goto` instead of `break` to jump to after the winning message is printed. Or you could make this into another function and change `break` to `return;`

Comment: You need to set some sort of flag(bool variable) to true if the user enters a 5 and then check that before you print the win message.

Comment: I am super amazed how fast everyone replied to this! Thank you all so much for the tips. Never ever really heard of boolean flags before. Thank you so very much :)

Comment: @Lucky.Tiger And this is what makes me sad, the community is often an obstacle for sensible but inexperienced programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to expand the scope if `i` and check that:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << "- enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    if (number == 5)
    {
      cout << "You were not supposed to enter 5!\n"; // Failure message
      break;
    }
}

if (i == 10)
{
    cout << "Wow, you're more patient than I am, you win.\n"; // winner message
}
```

Another would be to use a Boolean flag:

```
bool win = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << "- enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    if (number == 5)
    {
        cout << "You were not supposed to enter 5!\n"; // Failure message
        win = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (win)
{
    cout << "Wow, you're more patient than I am, you win.\n"; // winner message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop ends for one of 2 reasons: the user entered 10 non-5's, or they entered a 5 which breaks the loop.  So just check to see what the value of `number` is after the loop to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the whole `for` loop in a function that returns a boolean/int
and then call the function in an `if`

like:

```
if(game()==true)
   cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win.\n"; // winner message
else
   cout << "you were not supposed to enter 5!\n";  // Failure message
```

Putting the  thing in a function is homework :)

Tip: Replace the couts with returns inside the function ;)

Comment: `if (x == true)` is a pet peeve of mine. Why not just `if (game())`?

Comment: Of course you can do that too, didn't want to assume that you know it, it's just more obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use flag, one possible solution is (which also makes your code simpler):

```
bool win = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && win; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << "- enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    win = number != 5;
}
if( win ) 
    cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win.\n"; // winner message
else
    cout << "you were not supposed to enter 5!\n"; // Failure message
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple boolean flag will fix your problem.

```
bool enteredFive = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i + 1 << "- enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    if (number == 5)
    {
        cout << "You were not supposed to enter 5!" << endl;
        enteredFive = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!enteredFive)
    cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win!" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag variable [Here isFive] to check whether user ever entered 5 and print based on that decision.

```
bool isFive = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << "- enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    if (number == 5)
    { 
      isFive = true;
      cout << "you were not supposed to enter 5!\n"; // Failure message
      break;
    }
}
if(!isFive)
   cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win.\n"; // winner message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    std::cout << i + 1 << "- enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> number;

    if (number == 5)
    {
        std::cout << "you were not supposed to enter 5!\n"; // Failure message
        return 0;
    }
    
    
}
std::cout << "Wow, you're more patient than I am, you win.\n"; // winner message
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).